# SDL2 from source not finding any video drivers

Tags: linux, gcc, sdl-2

I am trying to compile SDL2 from source which I will then static link in another project. I've downloaded the source code [here](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php).

On a Ubuntu 18.04 machine I run the following commands:

```
./configure
make clean
make
```

The configure output then shows the following (note the found video drivers):

```
SDL2 Configure Summary:
Building Shared Libraries
Building Static Libraries
Enabled modules : atomic audio video render events joystick haptic sensor power filesystem threads timers file loadso cpuinfo assembly
Assembly Math   : mmx 3dnow sse sse2 sse3
Audio drivers   : disk dummy oss
Video drivers   : dummy opengl_es2 vulkan
Input drivers   : linuxev linuxkd
Using libsamplerate : NO
Using libudev       : NO
Using dbus          : NO
Using ime           : YES
Using ibus          : NO
Using fcitx         : NO
```

If I then use this library in my other project I get a runtime error saying: `SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: No available video device`.

Am I missing a step? I'm assuming X11 or Wayland should be linked against since I'm running on Ubuntu Desktop?

Comment: Show your code and compile command.

Comment: @Nelfeal, after further investigation I solved this problem by installing the `libsdl2-dev` package. I tried this previously but due to a bug in our build system (unrelated to this issue) this change was not properly applied.

Comment: Voting to close as "can't reproduce/typo" then.